# Getting error while executing Day Light script

Tags: plsql

select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2023-03-26 02:00:00.000000000 EUROPE/BERLIN','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR') from dual;

getting error: ORA-01878: specified field not found in datetime or interval

select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2023-03-26 02:00:00.000000000 EUROPE/BERLIN','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR') from dual;

Answer (score 1):

The function `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` takes a timezone offset, not a timezone name as argument. So for Europe/Berlin:

```
select TZ_OFFSET('Europe/Berlin') from dual;
+01:00
```

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2023-03-26 02:00:00.000000000 +01:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9 TZR') from dual;

26-MAR-23 02.00.00.000000000 AM
```

or concatenate it together:

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2023-03-26 02:00:00.000000000 '||TZ_OFFSET('Europe/Berlin'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9 TZR') from dual;

26-MAR-23 02.00.00.000000000 AM
```